# Hangfire: Can we run multiple queue parallelly?

Tags: parallel-processing, hangfire

I'm creating queue dynamically i.e. 1 2 3 4 5, This queue are created based on the user's request. each request create new queue.
Now all this queue are running one by one only, I would like to run parallel, So that each user can see their jobs are running rather than waiting for other user's task to be complete.

Comment: AFAIK parallel processing is the default behavior of Hangfire. Can you show some code so that people can see how you create the queues dynamically ? How do you register the queues server side so that HF server fetches it ?

Comment: @jbl, i agree parallel process is default behavior of HF. but what exactly i'm looking for is parallel queue. for example, i'm user and i want to perform 50 item set which will run parallelly by HF but now some other user also came and try to perform 30 item set then they need to wait for completion of my task.
where else i'm looking for all requested user's work should happen parallelly.

Please go through this article for generating dynamic queue at runtime
https://barelycompetent.co.za/hangfire-dynamic-queues/

Comment: From what I see in the article, each different queue is processed by a different server. So I don't see why another user would have to wait. Please show *your* code, especially the server configuration part.

Comment: Yes i have created multiple server with respect to queue. and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by creating multiple server with respect to queue.
for example, couple of queue on 1 server and few on another server.
code:
app.usehangfireserver(options1);
app.usehangfireserver(options2);